# lynx - Dump list of URL's into a single file?

Tags: bash, lynx

Is it possible to use lynx to dump a list of URL's in a text file all into 1 file?

I tried this but no luck

```
lynx -dump -width=1000 list.txt > dumped.txt
```

I also tried this but it didnt work eiter, just replaces the file it seems

```
    cat list.txt |while read url
do
    lynx -dump -width=1000 "$url" > dumped.txt
done
```

Comment: What's the contents of `list.txt`, and what are you expecting `dumped.txt` to contain?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The list.txt is 1 URL per line. I want to dump each URL into 1 large file. I think I have it now with this. But if anyone has a better suggestion then please let me know `cat list.txt |while read url
do
    lynx -dump -width=1000 "$url" | cat >> dumped.txt
done`

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding comments. Not all comments will be shown initially. Put everything in one place. Make it easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing this. Not sure if it's the best but it does work

```
    cat list.txt |while read url
do
    lynx -dump -width=1000 "$url" | cat >> dumps.txt
done
```

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, and you are close to a optimum solution, but try `while read url ; do lynx -dump -width=1000 "$url" >> dumps.txt ; done < list.txt` . Good luck.